# Express JS: Superagent does not use http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, superagent, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am writing a node application using express JS. Usually in this application we consumes res apis and merge them in one object and send it to angular application.
As a rest client I am using *superagent*. One of my colleague has written reverse proxy code using  *http-proxy-middleware*.

Using superagent I make a call like below and it does not use http-proxy-middleware as i have mentioned in code.

```
let request = require("superagent");    
request.get("applications-api/1/anotherendpoint")
            .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .set("x-application", applicationId)
            .then((response) => {
                res.send(response.body);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                   res.json(err)
            });
```

Usually http call should go through middleware since we have that middleware used in express server like but it does not do. In middleware we are using actual endpoint when path matches to **"^applications-api"**, but its not happening. Superagent expecting url which starts from *http://endpoint.com/1/anotherendpoint* but I want it to be used from proxy-middleware.

Is there anything to do with superagent configuration in order to use http-proxy-middleware ?
Kindly suggest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks